# Search over ssh with eclipse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eclipse, ssh

i have a working environment for my rails app hosted on vm.
I'm using Eclipse + Remote System Explorer on ubuntu to edit the files.

The thing is that i'm unable to use the remote search option (the search button seems to be greyed out).
It's pretty usefull and i will need it to improve productivity...

the thing i did for now was :
- add the ssh route on fstab
- search the files with the local search option

This method is not good for me cause i'm working on a vm so i need to do it all over again, and it only works on one particulare network...

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the VM issue by using kvm instead of virtualbox